# Business Objects Launch from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, business-intelligence, business-objects

I am in the process of creating a Business Objects macro for myself using VBA. I have found this code and others similar across the forums everywhere. However upon compiling this in VBA, everything just starts to freeze at the Set BoApp stage. Am I missing something in creating the object? Does the **BusinessObjects.application** have to say something else that is specific to my Business Objects directory?

Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub Open_Reports()
    Dim BoApp As Object

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("1:00:00"))

On Error Resume Next
Set BoApp = CreateObject("BusinessObjects.application")
With BoApp
    .Visible = True
    .LoginAs "username", "password", , "DVBOCEN-APP01"
    .documents.Open ("Q:\MI Reporting (BAU)\BAU Daily\Operational Reports\All reports\Sales - Advisor - Daily.rep")
         With .Activedocument
              .Refresh
              .Close
         End With
    .Application.Quit
End With

Set BoApp = Nothing

ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
.Quit
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it'll help, since it should work either way, but try:

```
Dim BoApp As busobj.Application
```

and

```
Set BoApp = New busobj.Application
```

I'm assuming you're able to successfully launch the DeskI application manually, and that you've added the BusinessObjects x Object Library as a reference?

Comment: Didn't add the library as a reference, assumed it would have already been on unfortunately. Successfully added the reference and made the suggestions you said and it worked! Thank you!